# API para obtenção de dados de cotações

Tags: php, json, api

Queria saber se existe alguma API que fornece dados (jSON ou XML) de cotações do dólar e euro. E também se possui alguma que forneça os indicadores dos valores e taxas de variação de produtos agrícolas, como: milho, soja, gado, etc. Se alguém conhecer ou até mesmo já trabalhou com uma API assim, agradeço!

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?